# Caching in Grails?

Tags: caching, grails, browser-cache, grails-2.0

Ist there something like a best practice for what is a good methodology to implement caching with grails? What plugins should be used and which parts of the page should be cached and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vast question depending on your needs.To cache domain objects you can use the Hibernate cache like this:

```
class Book {
    …
    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}
```

And configure Hibernate second level cache in `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

[Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cache.html) and [caching guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#caching).

You can also cache your controllers and services using [Grails cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cache) based on [Spring cache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html):

```
@Cacheable('message')
   Message getMessage(String title) {
      println 'Fetching message'
      Message.findByTitle(title)
   }
```

You'll find the excellent documentation [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-cache/).

If you want to cache rendered page you can also have a look at the [gsp template rendering cache plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/template-cache).